# minio admin panel error Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I build a folder in C:\minio and I run minio with the following command

```
minio server c:\minio\
```

[image]

but I'm getting this error in minio admin panel

Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem with the latest version, rolling back to the previous version worked fine.
`image version: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-07-17T15-43-14Z`

UPDATE
The latest version has fixed it.
`image version: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-07-24T17-09-31Z`